# Adding extra properties to an anonymous class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to add extra properties to an anonymous class (or create a new instance with the extra properties)?

```
string cssClasses = "hide";
object viewData = new { @class = cssClasses };
if (suppliedId != null)
{
  // add an extra id property to the viewData somehow...
  // desired end result is { @id = suppliedId, @class = cssClasses }
}
// ... code will be passing the viewData as the additionalViewData parameter in asp.mvc's .EditorFor method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from Patryk I gave it a go using an ExpandoObject and got it working like this:

```
dynamic viewData = new ExpandoObject();
viewData.@class = cssClasses;
if (controlId != null)
  viewData.id = controlId;
if (title != null)
  viewData.title = title;
// put the result into a route value dictionary so that MVC's EditorFor (etc) can interpret it
var additionalViewData = new RouteValueDictionary(viewData);
```

That last line was the key to getting it working in MVC so that  it could be passed as the additionalViewData parameter in EditorFor etc.

In the situations where I'm being passed an anonymous class and need to add to it myself, I'm using reflection (and taking advantage of ExpandoObject implementing IDictionary). Here's the unit test I wrote to check that it works:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldBeAbleToConvertAnAnonymousObjectToAnExpandoObject()
{
  var additionalViewData = new {id = "myControlId", css = "hide well"};
  dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
  var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)result;
  foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in additionalViewData.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
  {
    dict[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyInfo.GetValue(additionalViewData, null);
  }
  Assert.AreEqual(result.id, "myControlId");
  Assert.AreEqual(result.css, "hide well");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do it. You can redefine it, though:

```
dynamic viewData = new { @class = cssClasses };
if (suppliedId != null)
{
    viewData = new { @class = viewData.@class, yourExtra = Property };
}
```

Note that I changed it to `dynamic`. This is just so you can edit the properties without casting to `dynamic`.

Comment: Yep, either that or use `dynamic` with `ExpandoObject` instead :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Yeah, true. I quite like ExpandoObject tbh, it's pretty cool.

Comment: I don't understand why you didn't keep `object` in the code? Both anonymous types in question are `object`s.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Just so I didn't have to cast to `dynamic` to get the previous `viewData.@class`. It would be fine in this example, but if there was more properties, it would be uglier and less efficient for each property.

Comment: I see. He could also do something like this: `var viewDataSimple = new { @class = cssClasses }; var viewDataExtra = new { @class = viewData.@class, yourExtra = Property }; object viewDataToUse = suppliesId != null ? (object)viewDataExtra : (object)viewDataSimple;` Then he would keep two exactly typed references to the two distinct objects, and then have a third reference of type `object` to the relevant one of the two instances.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen True.

Comment: +1 Yeah, I was using a similar approach previously but it's getting out of hand now that there are several properties (each of which may or may not need to be added).

Answer (score 3):

You can not add extra properties to anonymous types, but you can use *two* anonymous types.

If you don't like `dynamic` (and there are reasons not to), you could do:

```
object viewData;
if (suppliedId == null)
    viewData = new { @class = cssClasses, };
else
    viewData = new { @id = suppliedId, @class = cssClasses, };
```

If you want to keep separate exactly typed references to each object instance, then use:

```
var viewDataSimple = new { @class = cssClasses, };
var viewDataExtra = new { @id = suppliedId, @class = cssClasses, };
object viewDataToUse;
if (suppliedId == null)
    viewDataToUse = viewDataSimple;
else
    viewDataToUse = viewDataExtra;
```

instead.

Comment: +1 Yep, that's exactly what I was doing. Now I've got a couple of extra properties though, so the number of permutations is getting out of hand.

Comment: @JonathanMoffatt Then maybe you do really want [the `ExpandoObject` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) in `System.Dynamic` namespace. It works exactly by adding new members as you go. See the examples on the link I gave there. Edit: Ah, just saw from your new answer that you already found out.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the requirement by using **Reflection**,You can add new property by KeyValue Pair.

```
string cssClasses = "hide";
        object viewData = new { @class = cssClasses };
        dynamic expandoData = new ExpandoObject();
        var processedData = expandoData as IDictionary<String, object>;
        if (viewData != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = viewData.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                if (prop == null) continue;
                object valueObj = viewData .GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(viewData , null);
                processedData[prop.Name.ToString()] = valueObj;
            }
        }           
        processedData["AdditionalPropertyName"] = AdditionalProperty;
        var infoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(processedData);
```

Comment: you should describe the solution you provided for now it's only a diff - not a proper answer